# Tool to generate online buttons (animated) and download all the sizes

Tags: android, android-button

Long time ago I used an online tool but I totally forgot about the name. I could upload an image and then the buttons were generated automatically (even the xml selector) and download all of the sizes at the same time (hdpi, mpi, etc..) for Android.

Do you know any tool to do that? Where I could upload a 9patch or image and generate all the buttons?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several awesome tools in the [Android Asset Studio](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html?utm_content=bufferbcc6a&utm_source=buffer&utm_medium=twitter&utm_campaign=Buffer):

- [Icons from clipart](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/icons-generic.html#source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&size=24&padding=8&color=33b5e5%2C100&name=ic_example)
- [Ninepatch generator](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/nine-patches.html)
- [Holo resources](http://android-holo-colors.com/)

Comment: It was the Holo resources what I was looking for! Thank you very much, you saved me some time!